# Android Lifecycle - does rotating screen doesn't destroys Activity anymore?

Tags: java, android, lifecycle

So I've just created a dummy app, to check the Activity Lifecycle, and I was surprised, that rotating the screen doesn't provide onDestroy() anymore, is it true, or I just messed something up? I've used the Log's, so it should appear.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: "+TAG);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStart: "+TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "onPostResume: "+TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(TAG, "onPause: "+TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStop: "+TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume: "+TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy: "+TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    Log.i(TAG, "onRestart: "+TAG);
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your manifests file

Answer (score 0):

No, I think was an update in Android, but is a good practice to keep it because they still have it another configuration, like maybe they can change the size of the text or the screen, but for rotation, you'll safe

Comment: If you want to see those logs, you'll need to use the classic wat, close the app, call a second activity, destroy the app